# printf - separate digit and sign

Tags: c, printf, digit

I need to seperate digit from sign. So, if I have digit 2635, I need it to be like this:

```
"+       2635."
```

Here is my code:

```
printf("%+-#13.4g\n", digit);
```

and what I'm getting is

```
"+2635.       "
```

Comment: Would `+0002635.` be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for a simpler answer, but in a pinch you can do this:

```
printf("%c%#13.4g\n", digit < 0 ? '-' : '+', fabs(digit));
```